# R check for outliers in multiple variables

Tags: r, group-by, outliers

I need to check my data fro outliers and I have 67 different variables. So I don't want to do it by hand. This is my code for checking it by hand (I have three factors to be checked - voiceID, gender and VP). But I don't know how I should change it to a loop that iterates over columns.

```
features %>%
  group_by(voiceID, gender, VP) %>%
  identify_outliers(meanF0)
```

The values are all numbers. The output should tell me which rows for what factors are outliers.
Thanks for help

Comment: Please show a small reproducble example and expected output.  Try `%>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), identify_outliers))`

Comment: @akrun this throws an error - Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x data should be a data frame

Comment: I assume that you have a function named `identify_outliers`

Comment: identify_outliers() is a build-in function from R

Comment: I couldn't find it with `?identify_outliers#
No documentation for ‘identify_outliers’ in specified packages and libraries:`

Comment: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/outliers.html

Comment: I suggest using `skim(df)` from the skimr package; it's often a better way to get to know the data. Then you can make your own decisions about what qualifies as an outlier and deal with them appropriately

Answer (score 0):

The output of `identify_outliers` is a `tibble` with multiple columns and it can take a single variable at a time.  The variable name can be either quoted or unquoted.  In that case, we can `group_split` the data by the grouping variables, then loop over the columns of interest, and apply the `identify_outliers`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rstatix)
nm1 <- c("score", "score2")
 demo.data %>%
     group_split(gender) %>%
        map(~  map(nm1, function(x) .x %>% 
                identify_outliers(x)))
```

---

If we want to count the outliers,

```
features %>%
   group_by(voiceID, gender, VP)  %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ length(boxplot(., plot = FALSE)$out)))
```

Comment: It works, but even when I specify just a few variables in nm1, the output shows me all columns from demo.data. It looks very messy and I cannot see if the output are just outliers or extreme outliers. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I understand the issue.  It is better to show a small reproducible example with `dput` in your post and expected output so that it becomes easier as there is a frame of reference.  My idea with this code was to show a way to apply on different columns.  As I noted, the output is a data.frame and I am not sure which format you wanted the expected output

Comment: I understand, but I found out, that I can't see if an outlier is extreme or not because I have so many column (so not good to make a reproduciple example of it here). Is there a way to show the rows with only extreme outliers?

Comment: or to count the extreme outliers for each variable?

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I updated for the `count`ing of extreme values